# a question about Kirillov model of unitary representations over GL_n(R)

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $F$ be either a p-adic field or real number field. $GL_{n-1}(F)$ embeds into $GL_n(F)$ on the left upper corner, let $P_n(F)$ be the mirabolic subgroup of $G_n(F)$ consisting of matrices with the last low like $(0,0,...,0,1)$. So we have inclusions $GL_{n-1}(F)\subset P_n(F)$.

When $F$ is p-adic, let $(\pi,V)$ be a generic irreducible admissible smooth representation of $GL_n(F)$, with its Whittaker model $\mathcal{W}(\pi)$. It is well known that for any $W_v(g)\in \mathcal{W}(\pi)$, the restriction map sending $W_v$, as a function of $GL_n$, to $W_v|_{GL(n-1)}$ ,

is injective, and from here we obtain the Kirillov model of $\pi$ as a space of functions on $GL_{n-1}$ .

My question is that when $F=\mathbb{R}$, and $\pi$ is unitary, in which case we also have Kirillov model for $\pi$, but I'm not sure if it comes in the same way as we described above in p-adic case. I don't know the exact reference containing the proof that $\pi$ has Kirillov model, and thus have no idea how it comes.

Another question is that when $F=\mathbb{R}$, $\pi$ a generic smooth irreducible admissible, is it still true for any Whittaker function $W_v$ of $\pi$, the restriction of $W_v$ to $GL(n-1)$ as above is injective, which implies we again have a Kirillov model for $\pi$.

Any answer, comment and reference are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to glance through [Cogdell's](http://www.math.osu.edu/~cogdell/) "L-functions and Converse Theorems for GL(n)" (in Sarnak/Shahidi "Automorphic Forms and Applications), which cites Jacquet and Shalika's "On Euler Products and the Classification of Automorphic Forms I", available from Jacquet's [website](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~hj/), as answering your question in the affirmative (see Section 1.3): the map $\xi\rightarrow W_\xi|_P$ in injective (where $P$ is the mirabolic subgroup), moreover, the Kirillov model (of a generic irreducible unitary representation), defined as the space of restrictions of Whittaker functions, is isomorphic to ${\rm Ind}_N^P(\psi)$ as representations of $P$.